# How to make create value comma sepreted?

Tags: php

I know how to loop through items of an array using foreach and append a comma, but it's always a pain having to take off the final comma. Is there an easy PHP way of doing it?

```
$result = "apple, banana, pear, grape"
```

I want to

```
$fruit = array('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'grape');
```

Comment: [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) ?

Comment: @iainn please link only english documentation. Your link is barely useless

Comment: @Simo Edited. No idea how that happened, I definitely don't speak Russian

Comment: Seriously we don't have a dupe question for this?

Comment: Showing what you have and *then* what you want to get to, is a more common way here to present your problem. Starting the the desired result, gives you some unexpected and not that useful - to you - answers :-)

Answer (score 8):

Your question description seems to imply that you want to convert comma-separated string to an array. To do that, use [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. From documentation:

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
>
> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Try the following code (note the **space after comma** in the delimiter string):

```
$result = "apple, banana, pear, grape";
$fruit = explode(', ', $result);
```

Now, if you want to do the **reverse** (convert Array to String), use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function instead. Try the following code:

```
$fruit = array('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'grape');
$result = implode(', ', $fruit);
```

Comment: Isn't `$result` supposed to be the output, not the input?

Comment: @iainn No. Please check OP's question. his variable naming is other way around :P

Comment: @NextTechnology you need an array - as per your question!

Comment: $result = "apple, banana, pear, grape";  
I need
$result = array("apple, banana, pear, grape");

Comment: @NextTechnology - This will give you an array (which is what you asked for). How do you output it when you get `Array`? Your question is _very_ ambiguous. Do you want a comma separated string or an array?

Comment: @NextTechnology check the edited answer. I have added both the cases- Use implode function if you want to do array to string

Comment: @NextTechnology Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`$result = "apple, banana, pear, grape, ";`

Use rtrim function

`rtrim($my_string,',');`

The second parameter indicates the character to be deleted.

Comment: your answer is good but you need to precise that it is after foreach use

Comment: Thanks, Elementary for correcting me yes after foreach you can remove the last comma from your string.